# Map not showing in APK but showing in Emulator

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Guys can anyone solve my problem I have created my new Flutter app but the problem is map is not showing on my android device but it will show on the emulator I have search many times this issue on google but I never found that

Answer (score 0):

On the emulator, you are compiling in debug mode. Which gives the app a lot of permission. In the release mode, you have to add the permissions.
I think you should check your Android manifest file for missing permissions.
Maybe these can be related to your problem:
INTERNET
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

Comment: Yes I set my location  and also I have access all things in manifest file

Answer (score 0):

Showing of maps corresponds to API key added in the project and SHA of signing certificate added on Google API console for that API Key.

Things to check:

1.) Check if there is separate file from where your API key is fetched on release build and check if there is value added on it.

2.) Add the SHA of signing certificate on Google API Console against above API key.

Comment: ye I also add the API Key and it fetches on release build but sill not showing In release APK

Comment: Have you added SHA of release signing certificate on Google API console??

Comment: Yes I added the SHA key on the google console but nothing will show

Comment: DO you get any error on Logcat?? Please add some error you are getting on your logcat. As you said you have added 2 SHA on Google Console, one of debug signing certificate and another of release signing certificate then there would some another issue which you might see on your Logcat.